# Clone git repository over ssh with username and password by Java

Tags: java, git, ssh, jgit

I am trying to clone a git project with Java over ssh. I have username and password of a git-shell user as credentials. I can clone the project in terminal using the following command with no problem. (Of course, it asks for the password first)

```
git clone user@HOST:/path/Example.git
```

However when I try the following code using JGIT api

```
File localPath = new File("TempProject");
Git.cloneRepository()
    .setURI("ssh://HOST/path/example.git")
    .setDirectory(localPath)
    .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("***", "***"))
    .call();
```

I got

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://HOST/path/example.git: Auth fail
```

What should I do? Any ideas? (I am using OSX 10.9.4 and JDK 1.8)

Comment: You probably can use `http` for git repo URI if you want to use Username and password as credential provider.

Comment: user name and password are for ssh user on Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Maybe something related to jgit.transport.SshConfigSessionFactory???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For authentication with SSH, JGit uses [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). JSch provides an `SshSessionFactory` to create and dispose SSH connections. The quickest way to tell JGit which SSH session factory should be used is to set it globally through `SshSessionFactory.setInstance()`.

JGit provides an abstract `JschConfigSessionFactory`, whose `configure` method can be overridden to provide the password:

```
SshSessionFactory.setInstance( new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
    @Override
    protected void configure( Host host, Session session ) {
      session.setPassword( "password" );
    }
} );
Git.cloneRepository()
  .setURI( "ssh://username@host/path/repo.git" )
  .setDirectory( "/path/to/local/repo" )
  .call();
```

To set the `SshSessionFactory` in a more sensible way is slightly more complex. The `CloneCommand` - like all JGit command classes that may open a connection - inherits from `TransportCommand`. This class has a `setTransportConfigCallback()` method that can also be used to specify the SSH session factory for the actual command.

```
CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
cloneCommand.setTransportConfigCallback( new TransportConfigCallback() {
  @Override
  public void configure( Transport transport ) {
    if( transport instanceof SshTransport ) {
      SshTransport sshTransport = ( SshTransport )transport;
      sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory( ... );
    }
  }
} );
```

Comment: @NuriTasdemir I've enhanced the answer with your code snippet and I recommend to revert the question to its original form to preserve the Q&A character. Others will find the _best_ answer as the first one (and that may be a different one than mine in the future).

Comment: In order to compile this code in Eclipse I had to include jsch.jar (for the com.jcraft.jsch.Session) However this time when I run the program (which is an Eclipse plugin that depends on jgit plugin), I got the following error. java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader previously initiated loading for a different type with name "com/jcraft/jsch/Session" Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that this is related to [bug 420903](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420903)? Otherwise I recommend to post a separate question and provide more details about JGit version, JSch version, your bundle manifest, etc.

Comment: I post it as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102649/java-lang-linkageerror-while-using-jgit-and-jsch-for-eclipse-plugin-development